# Add Value from one Row to another Row with Same Primary Key- Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, primary-key

I would like to create an update statement that adds a value from one row to the value of another row with the same ID field. Basically wherever TYPE = 'ASB' and TEMP = 'DELETE' i would like to add the AMOUNT value to the AMOUNT where TYPE = 'CON'.

This has to be done for each ID. COMBINE Field can be used as a unique identifier for each row. Perhaps a windows function? Any help is much appreciated!

```
Current Result:
ID          TYPE         AMOUNT        COMBINE      TEMP
0432        CMP         12828.77      0432CMP   
0432        CON         -2083.26      0432CON   
0432        ASB         1704.03       0430ASB      DELETE

Expected Result:
ID          TYPE         AMOUNT        COMBINE      TEMP
0432        CMP         12828.77      0432CMP   
0432        CON         -379.23       0432CON   
0432        ASB         1704.03       0432ASB      DELETE
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `MERGE` statement as follows:

```
MERGE INTO YOUR_TABLE TRG USING 
(
    SELECT ID, SUM(AMOUNT) AS AMOUNT
    FROM YOUR_TABLE
    WHERE TYPE = 'ASB' AND TEMP = 'DELETE'
    GROUP BY ID
) SRC 
ON ( SRC.ID = TRG.ID AND TRG.TYPE = 'CON' )
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
UPDATE SET TRG.AMOUNT = TRG.AMOUNT + SRC.AMOUNT;
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

An `update` should do it:

```
update t
    set amount = amount +
                 (select coalesce(sum(t2.amount), 0)
                  from t t2
                  where t2.id = t.id and t2.type = 'ASB' and t2.temp = 'DELETE'
                 )
    where t.type = 'CON' and
          exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.id = t.id and t2.type = 'ASB' and t2.temp = 'DELETE'
                 );
```